# Error from UglifyJs - Unexpected token: name (Subject)

Tags: angular, typescript, uglifyjs

I'm trying to deploy my first Angular application. However, it doesn't build - error I'm getting is:

> ERROR in vendor.809dd4effe018f6b3d20.bundle.js from UglifyJs
>   Unexpected token: name (Subject) [vendor.809dd4effe018f6b3d20.bundle.js:22197,6]

I've tried googling it, but all I've found is that Uglify doesn't support ES6. Ok, but my typescript is configured to compile to ES5...

Could it be that a npm module is in ES6 and I need to use babel? That's the only thing that comes to my mind.

My app is using Angular 4, typescript's target is es5.

Answer (score 0):

Last time also i got this error when i've built the app wit AOT. Also i have same setup with yours, target: 'es5', etc. I tried everything but couldn't find solution for this except removing the last installed npm package which is 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereum-blockies-png'. When i removed this package, then build was without this error. Please check up libraries that you've installed.